# How to change keyboard shortcut - F5 to Ctrl + Enter to execute SQL command in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to change the execute keyboard shortcut from <kbd>F5</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd> in SQL Server Management Studio.

I tried to open Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Keyboard and selected query.executed and set my key as <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>, but when I execute my command in SSMS using <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>, my query is not getting executed, I had to press <kbd>F5</kbd> again to actually execute my statement.

Comment: When you changed the setting for `query.executed` to you ensure you selected the [Global setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QGPA.png) or the SQL Query Editor setting in the drop down?

Comment: Note as well that the F5 shortcut will always persist. You will be changing the Global or SQL Query Editor shortcuts (`Alt`+`X` and `Ctrl`+`E` respectively).

Comment: @Larnu, i tried with global setting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Keyboard > Find Query.Execute
Choose Text Editor And Assign new Key

[image]

Comment: i tried this, it is not working for  me and when i go to this option again and check, i cannot find this shortcut ( Query.Execute(Ctrl+Enter)) in the Shortcut currently used by section

Comment: It happened to me too. in my case i forgot to press the Assign key!

Comment: i did press the assign key still it is not happening

Comment: i also tried to restart the ssms after i assigned the keyboard shortcut and click on assign and ok

Comment: This is odd!I just tired on my ssms and it worked!

Comment: thank, it worked, i forgot to change the (use new shortcut key in ) from global to Text Editor

Comment: when i have multiple statements, i would like to execute only the command, where the cursor is located, because it takes time to mark the text between two `;`.